# Merge specific child nodes in xml using python

Tags: python, xml

I want to merge certain sub elements of xml file together.  The following is the format I have:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?><?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='image_metadata_stylesheet.xsl'?><dataset><name>imglab dataset</name><comment>Created by imglab tool.</comment><images>
<image file='/home/user126043/Documents/testimages/9935.jpg'>
<box top='329' left='510' width='385' height='534'>
<label>Pirelli
</label></box></image>
<image file='/home/user126043/Documents/testimages/9935.jpg'>
<box top='360' left='113' width='440' height='147'>
<label>Pirelli
</label></box></image>
<image file='/home/user126043/Documents/testimages/9921.jpg'>
<box top='329' left='510' width='385' height='534'>
<label>Pirelli
</label></image>
</images></dataset>
```

In the above xml I have the box coordinates of image 99.jpg specified twice which I want to merge into one.  I want to remove the `<image>` tag that appears repeatively for the same image and want to merge all the box coordinates for every single image within its own image tags.  I have never worked with XML and hence I am not sure if the definitions that I use is right here or not. The desired output is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?><?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='image_metadata_stylesheet.xsl'?><dataset><name>imglab dataset</name><comment>Created by imglab tool.</comment><images>
    <image file='/home/user126043/Documents/testimages/9935.jpg'>
    <box top='329' left='510' width='385' height='534'>
    <label>Pirelli
    </label></box>
    <box top='360' left='113' width='440' height='147'>
    <label>Pirelli
    </label></box></image>
    <image file='/home/user126043/Documents/testimages/9921.jpg'>
    <box top='329' left='510' width='385' height='534'>
    <label>Pirelli
    </label></image>
    </images></dataset>
```

Comment: fyi: you can use an XML validator to check your xml https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator/cba0c900. as you can see it is "valid"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with module [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('dataset.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
file_dict = dict()
for image in root.iter('image'):    
    file_str = image.get('file')    
    if file_str in file_dict:
        root.find('images').remove(image) #remove the duplicate one
        root.find('images').find("./image[@file='"+file_str+"']").append(image.find('box')) #append duplicated subelement to merge with same image element
    else:
        file_dict[file_str]=image
print(ET.tostring(root))
```

The new `root` will be:

```
<dataset><images>
<image file="/home/user126043/Documents/testimages/9941.jpg">
<box height="147" left="113" top="360" width="440">
<label>Pirelli
</label></box></image>
<image file="/home/user126043/Documents/testimages/99.jpg">
<box height="276" left="247" top="160" width="228">
<label>Pirelli
</label></box><box height="276" left="247" top="439" width="506">
<label>Pirelli
</label></box></image>
</images></dataset>
```

Comment: Many thanks...I tried using the code...but getting the following error.. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 337, in remove
    self._children.remove(element)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Comment: are you sure you are using the same code, please note that `root[0].remove(image)` not `root.remove(image)`

Comment: can you print out your root[0] with `print(ET.tostring(root[0]))` before the remove?

Comment: Thanks a ton for your message...the following is the output`<name>imglab dataset</name>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clrxml2.py", line 9, in <module>
    root[0].remove(image) #remove the duplicate one
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 337, in remove
    self._children.remove(element)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Comment: Not sure if the error is because of the name tag....I am updating the xml again for your reference

Comment: @Apricot, change all `root[0]` to `root.find('images')`, check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a tonne....have been trying to get this working for the last 3 days...the change from [0] to .find worked...